# Tomcat 9 can't find org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I am running tomcat 9.0.64.0 and I made a JDBC resource in server.xml.

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/ub" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30"
            maxWaitMillis="10000" username="ub" password="mypw"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://biglongamazonurl:3306/UB" />
```

I get this error on startup, before the application even loads. I have mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar in tomcat's lib. I also see tomcat-dbcp.jar in lib. Why can't the server find org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory?

```
24-Mar-2023 19:20:21.777 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource Failed to register in JMX: [javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]]
24-Mar-2023 19:20:21.857 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans Exception processing global JNDI Resources
    javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getDefaultFactory(ResourceFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:92)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:342)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:864)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:115)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:69)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:32)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:82)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:923)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getDefaultFactory(ResourceFactory.java:50)
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: also note I have the dependency 
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
in my application's POM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this line in tomcat9.conf, commenting it fixed the issue:

```
#JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.sql.DataSource.Factory=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be providing the DBCP libraries along with your own application, unless you are managing the JDBC pool yourself. Tomcat ships with all the classes necessary to manage its connection pool.

The class that isn't being found is `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory` which is the wrong factory class for that version of Tomcat. Tomcat 9 ships with a package-renamed version of DBCP2 whose proper factory class is `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory`. The difference is the package name `org.apache.*tomcat*` and `dbcp2`.

You must be manually-specifying the factory class name for the connection pool somewhere. Usually this is done by specifying the `factory` attribute in your `<Resource>` but you do not have one in the config you posted. Is there *another* configuration somewhere that might be causing this problem? Maybe you are reporting a problem with `<Resource>` A but it's really `<Resource>` B that is failing. Try using `grep` (or equivalent) on all files in your project / deployment for that failing class name, then remove that configuration and use the "correct" DBCP that ships with Tomcat 9.

Comment: I had this line in tomcat9.conf, removing it fixed the issue: #JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.sql.DataSource.Factory=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"

Comment: @JesseBarnum That would cause the kind of problem you described. Unless you have a really good reason to do so, you should not specify the data source factory, and if you *are* going to do it, you should do it in a more discoverable place such as `META-INF/context.xml` right inside the `<Resource>` definition.

Comment: @JesseBarnum IS RIGHT! I had to do a reinstall and org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory is specifically listed in tomcat.conf. I removed that and it was fixed. Jesse, if you want to make that an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @SamDonato There is no file called `tomcat.conf` that ships with Tomcat. You must have gotten it from somewhere else.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz you think we are both making it up? I did a few installs on an AWS EC2. "amazon-linux-extras install tomcat9" try it yourself. Might have also been from here yum install tomcat-webapps tomcat-admin-webapps.

Comment: @SamDonato I'm not saying you are making it up. I'm just saying that Tomcat doesn't ship with such a configuration. Your package-manager may be supplying that file and breaking things. You should file a ticket with them, because Tomcat does not have this problem in the official packaging.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put two jars in my /usr/share/tomcat9/lib directory

Apache Commons DBCP - 1.4 version
https://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/dbcp/binaries/

Apache Commons Pool(1)
https://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/pool/binaries/ I chose 1.4 version for no other reason than it matched the DBCP library